# Android Launch Mode Single Task

Tags: android, launchmode

In my app i have a dashboard activity and it's launch mode is "SingleTask" Are there any chances that my app gets in onNewIntent without onCreate?

For example if user navigates to another activity from Dashboard and after Dashboard is destroyed, what happens if user navigates to dashboard again?

Will onCreate work or just will go on from onNewIntent?

Thanks.

Comment: OnNewIntent is not for your scenario. Please learn about Activity lifecycle :https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Android API docs, `onNewIntent` will only get called for:

> activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or
>   if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling
>   startActivity(Intent).

Since you are using `SingleTask`, `onNewIntent` should not get called.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: OnNewIntent will be called when the singleTask activity started in a task which already includes the activity.